# google api is already presented in react app

Tags: reactjs, api, key

"google api is already presented"

[image: Screen shoot error explanation]

**1.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE API KEY0&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        function init() {

            var options = {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: {country: "au"}
            };

            var input = document.getElementById('citySearch');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    </script>
```

**2**

```
  return (
    <div className="googleMapContainer">
      {console.log(window.google)}
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={googleApiKey}>
        <div className="googleMap">
          <GoogleMap
```

how to handle this ?
one api key is in index.html and other one is trying to use api key as props for component react-google-maps

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else finds this google offers another API for loading the scripts rather than using `<LoadScript>`.

```
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: 'google-map-script',
    googleMapsApiKey: 'YOUR API KEY HERE',
    libraries: ['geometry', 'drawing'],
  });
```

Then you can just use `isLoaded` later on:

```
{isLoaded && <GoogleMap
  onLoad={saveMap}
  mapContainerClassName={classes.mapContainer}
  mapContainerStyle={containerSize}
  center={DefaultCenterPoint}
  options={options}
>
  {mapItems}
</GoogleMap>}
```

This automatically handles if the maps API has already been loaded :)

Comment: Yes, but this is not working for class components right ?

Answer (score 3):

Try `<GoogleMap />` without `<LoadScript />` in the code 2. Check more [here](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/70#issuecomment-477493460)

Alternatively you can move the LoadScript to a parent component that doesn't render much, preferably close to the root of your tree.

Answer (score 2):

you must use the first check if the script is laoded before loading it again here is the sample code on react.js
`{window.google === undefined ?  <LoadScript><GoogleMap /></LoadScript> : <GoogleMap />}`

Answer (score 1):

You get an error message `google API is already presented in react app` when you try to load google maps API more than once. For your case, you loaded google API script `<script ... />` from your first snippet. You also used `<LoadScript .../>` in your second snippet, which does the same.

So, to get rid of that error you have to load Google Maps API once.